# Sending custom Props to component with Form in React and AntD, jsx.element

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd

I have a component which renders a form in React and it looks as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'antd';
import { FormComponentProps } from 'antd/lib/form';

const { Option } = Select;
type FormProps = FormComponentProps;

const SetupModuleForm = (props: FormProps): JSX.Element => {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;    
    return (
      <div className="mb-3 row">            
            <Form style={{marginTop: '15px'}} layout="vertical" hideRequiredMark >
               //Form stuff here
            </Form>                    
      </div>
    );
}
export const SetupModule = Form.create()(SetupModuleForm);
```

I am using it in my code to display the form as follows:

```
 <SetupModule />
```

What I would like to do is send some data into my setup module component as follows:

```
 <SetupModule myData={data} />
```

However, when I do that I am getting this error:

> Type '{ myData: ModuleSetupModel[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes, "wrappedComponentRef">, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.
>     Property 'myData' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes, "wrappedComponentRef">, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.

How can I pass my data to that component?

Comment: could you create a code sandbox?